# Enable ThriftParquetWriter to write 16-bit ints as short instead of converting it to 32-bit integer

Tags: java, parquet, thrift

I have a thrift class with `i16` field, which I try to write as parquet using `org.apache.parquet.thrift.ThriftParquetWriter`.
Unfortunately, this field **is automatically converted to `32-bit` integer**, which is not acceptable in my case.

As the [documentation](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format#types) says,

> 16-bit ints are not explicitly supported in the storage format since they are covered by 32-bit ints with an efficient encoding.

**How do I defile a custom converter/serializer for my `16-bit` integer field?**

There seem to be some logical type annotations, which might help, but it's unclear for me how and what should I annotate. Are there any examples?
https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/LogicalTypes.md#numeric-types

My parquet writer creation looks like this:

```java
ThriftParquetWriter writer = new ThriftParquetWriter(
                outPutPathInS3,
                Class.forName("com.mycompany.MyClass"),
                CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY,
                BLOCK_SIZE,
                PAGE_SIZE,
                ParquetWriter.DEFAULT_IS_DICTIONARY_ENABLED,
                ParquetWriter.DEFAULT_IS_VALIDATING_ENABLED,
                conf);
```

And I write my thrift data to parquet like this:

```java
for (TBase trecord : recordsToFlush) {
    writer.write(trecord);
}
```